# Use set from _set.all() and filter with __in with the set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Say I am a Tribal Chief overlooking has tribe activity. I have 3 models:

```
class Hunter:
   tribes = models.ManyToManyField(Tribe)
   info

class Missions:
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    info

class Tribe:
    tribe_chief = models.ForeignKey(User) #directed towards Chief
    info
```

And as a chief I have 
views.py (tribepk passed through URL)

```
user = request.user
tribe_instance = Tribe.objects.get(pk=tribepk)
myhunters = tribe_instance.hunter_set.all()
allmissions = Mission.objects.filter(user__in=myhunters)
```

So everything populates except for allmissions. Is it possible to user a _set.all() result as a filter criteria? Thanks

If it helps, this is what is returned in myhunters ->

```
'myhunters': [<Hunter: test>, <Hunter: asdf>, <Hunter: more>]
```

Comment: Does the `Hunter` model has the `user` field in it?

Answer (score 4):

So Mission has a `ForiegnKey` to `User` and not `Hunter`.  So you are passing in `Hunter` instances when it is expecting a list of users.

You can either change your model such that you have a `ForiegnKey` to `User` in your `Hunter` model.

```
class Hunter:
   tribes = models.ManyToManyField(Tribe)
   user = models.ForiegnKey(User)

allmissions = Mission.objects.filter(user__id__in=[myhunter.user.id for myhunter in myhunters])
```

Or you could just have `Mission` have a `ForiegnKey` to `Hunter`.

```
class Missions:
    user = models.ForeignKey(Hunter)
    info

allmissions = Mission.objects.filter(user__in=myhunters)
```

Edit: Updating the lookup on the first option to be less expensive as Aamir Adnan points out in the comments.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the current question.

Comment: @TimEdgar Would be nice if you could use the ids of users in the lookup `user__id__in=[myhunter.user.id for myhunter in myhunters]` to make the lookup less expensive.